# .net 5 retrieve HttpRequestMessage from HttpRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am doing a proof of concept to convert from our old .Net framework services to a .Net Core Web Api service.

We are using the AspNetCore.CacheOutput successor to StrathWeb. We now have a CacheOutputOverrideAttribute class and an OnActionExecuting method with the signature

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
```

The original code had the following signature. It was easy to get the HttpRequestMessage from that using actionContext.Request.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
```

In the old code, there were lines of code that utilized the HttpRequestMessage like the following.

```
var config = actionContext.Request.GetConfiguration();
```

Now, I can only get to the HttpResponse instead of the HttpResponseMessage. Is there a way to convert and extract the HttpResponseMessage from the HttpResponse?

Is there some other path that I should be using?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you need HttpResponseMessage for?  I don't think that you need it just for sake of HttpResponseMessage . What kind of information you need to extract?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `HttpResponseMessage`/`HttpRequestMesssage` or the base implementations in ASP.NET Core. There is only `HttpResponse`/`HttpRequest`. These new types are extensible unlike the old ASP.NET ones.

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve `HttpRequestMessage` from `HttpRequest` you can utilize the extension method `GetHttpRequestMessage` for the `HttpContext` object, provided by the `microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.webapicompatshim` package:

```cs
var httpRequestMessage = request.HttpContext.GetHttpRequestMessage();
```

Read more:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.webapicompatshim.httprequestmessagehttpcontextextensions.gethttprequestmessage?view=aspnetcore-2.2

In the context of Azure Functions this shim package is already referenced by   the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http` package.